# AWS Cognito Update lambda-config for CustomEmailSender erro

Tags: amazon-cognito

Scenario: I want to use third party service to send email, according to AWS document need to configure User pool `LambdaConfig` property. While update command in aws sdk

`aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id ${user-pool-id} --lambda-config "CustomEmailSender={LambdaVersion=V1_0,LambdaArn=${LAMBDA-ARN}},KMSKeyId=${KMS-ARN}"`

Getting error:

```
Unknown parameter in LambdaConfig: "CustomEmailSender", must be one of: PreSignUp, CustomMessage, PostConfirmation, PreAuthentication, PostAuthentication, DefineAuthChallenge, CreateAuthChallenge, VerifyAuthChallengeResponse, PreTokenGeneration, UserMigration
Unknown parameter in LambdaConfig: "KMSKeyId", must be one of: PreSignUp, CustomMessage, PostConfirmation, PreAuthentication, PostAuthentication, DefineAuthChallenge, CreateAuthChallenge, VerifyAuthChallengeResponse, PreTokenGeneration, UserMigration
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your CLI, my `aws --version` was a bit behind after upgrading it worked.

Thanks to [this post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUMDeW067iQc6W_8surgOfRA/error-when-update-cognito-pool-for-a-customemailsender)